# Print PDF LOCATE in my Computer with JAVA

Tags: java, pdf

I have more as 10000 PDF File locate in my Computer. I want to write a Java App to find the Right Name for the PDF and Print it.

Somebody can help how to print it?

Thank for Answers
 I have try this

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile;
import com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage;
import com.sun.pdfview.PDFRenderer;

 /**
 * Converts the PDF content into printable format
 */
 public class PrintPdf {

private PrinterJob pjob = null;

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 throws IOException, PrinterException    {
    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.err.println("The first parameter must have 
the location of the PDF file to be printed");
    }
    System.out.println("Printing: " + args[0]);
    // Create a PDFFile from a File reference
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    PrintPdf printPDFFile = new PrintPdf(fis, "Test Print PDF");
    printPDFFile.print();
}

/**
 * Constructs the print job based on the input stream
 * 
 * @param inputStream
 * @param jobName
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws PrinterException
 */
public PrintPdf(InputStream inputStream, String jobName) 
 throws IOException, PrinterException {
    byte[] pdfContent = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    inputStream.read(pdfContent, 0, inputStream.available());
    initialize(pdfContent, jobName);
 }

/**
 * Constructs the print job based on the byte array content
 * 
 * @param content
 * @param jobName
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws PrinterException
 */
public PrintPdf(byte[] content, String jobName)
throws IOException,   PrinterException {
    initialize(content, jobName);
}

/**
 * Initializes the job
 * 
 * @param pdfContent
 * @param jobName
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws PrinterException
 */
private void initialize(byte[] pdfContent,  
 String jobName) throws     IOException, PrinterException {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(pdfContent);
    // Create PDF Print Page
    PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(bb);
    PDFPrintPage pages = new PDFPrintPage(pdfFile);

    // Create Print Job
    pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PageFormat pf = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();
    pjob.setJobName(jobName);
    Book book = new Book();
    book.append(pages, pf, pdfFile.getNumPages());
    pjob.setPageable(book);

    // to remove margins
    Paper paper = new Paper();
    paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());
    pf.setPaper(paper);
}

public void print() throws PrinterException {
    // Send print job to default printer
    pjob.print();
 }
 }

  /**
 * Class that actually converts the PDF file into Printable format
*/
 class PDFPrintPage implements Printable {

private PDFFile file;

PDFPrintPage(PDFFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int index) 
throws   PrinterException {
    int pagenum = index + 1;
    if ((pagenum >= 1) && (pagenum <= file.getNumPages())) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        PDFPage page = file.getPage(pagenum);

        // fit the PDFPage into the printing area
        Rectangle imageArea = new Rectangle((int)
 format.getImageableX(),    (int) format.getImageableY(), 
                (int) format.getImageableWidth(),
(int)      format.getImageableHeight());
        g2.translate(0, 0);
        PDFRenderer pgs = new PDFRenderer(page, g2, imageArea, null, null);
        try {
            page.waitForFinish();
            pgs.run();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // nothing to do
        }
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    } else {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
  }
 }
```

I have this Error when i tried the above Code
Unable to read image width: Array, length=2     at com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage.createImage(Unknown Source)

Comment: @Raptor I have edit the Post

Comment: You should post the code here, instead of external link.

Comment: I update the Post

Comment: @Raptor It works now.